How to integrate upgraded openssl with already installed python on windows
I have a requirement where I need to integrate openssl with python on windows.
Previously I had openssl 3.0.9 installed, then I gave installed 3.0.14 and I have added the PATH in the environment variables.
When I entered 'openssl version', I see the latest version but when I tried to import the ssl using the python(3.11.5) which is already installed then it still shows me openssl version as 3.0.9.
Do I need to reinstall python? or is there any way to integrate the latest installed openssl with already installed python?
What did I try - I have tried installing latest openssl
What am expecting is - via python, import statement, I should able to import latest installed openssl

Are you using pyOpenSSL? If so (and sorry if this is a dumb question) but did you run pip install --upgrade pyOpenSSL?

I have installed openssl separately that I need to integrate with python.
